# Was Banacek episode "No Sign of the Cross" edited?

Tags: banacek

I was just watching the old (1972) TV series "Banacek" on streaming video.

WARNING -- SPOILER

In the episode "No Sign of the Cross", Banacek find the missing million-dollar crucifix hidden inside a cheap-looking wooden crucifix in a house in Mexico. In a crucial scene, he says that the wooden crucifix was suspicious because it had written on it "Jesus Died for Our Sins" in English, but the owner of the house was a Mexican who didn't know any English. I could have sworn that when this episode originally aired on TV, the crucial clue was that the wooden crucifix didn't have a Christ-figure hanging on it, and Banacek says that he knew that it was fake because the owner of the house was a devout Catholic -- Catholics routinely put a Christ figure on their crosses, Protestants do not.

Okay, looking at the dates I see that that's a memory from almost 50 years ago. (Wow, I'm getting old.) Does anyone else remember what Banacek said when the episode originally aired on TV? I wonder if it was changed because somebody found it offensive for some reason, or because this clue was considered too cryptic. Understanding it would require knowing differences between Catholic and Protestant symbology. Or am I just mis-remembering after all these years? Maybe jumbled what someone else said they thought would have been a better clue with what was actually in the show or something.

Answer (score 1):

Coincidence, that I watched the episode yesterday also. Found them on Amazon Prime this week. I was thrilled to find the whole series and started to rewatch.

To answer your question. I actually remember the original episode when it aired, I was young and it very hazily and I do not believe it was edited. So to be sure I just pulled the scene up again and I do not think it is possible to re-edit and dub that in at this later date.

Comment: If it was re-edited, I'd strongly suspect it was very shortly after the original filming. When the actor talks about English vs Spanish, it sounds like the original actor's voice, not some later actor dubbed in. I suppose it's possible they got someone good at mimicking voices. And the picture of the cross with the words in English fits in very smoothly with the rest of the program, it doesn't look like it was spliced in. So yeah, that would be evidence against an edit. It would have had to be done when the original actor and set was still available.